# Vuejs with innerhtml

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

There is a filter page.

| Filter | | content |

The filter is in the view, the content that is initially displayed is in Ruby. If a filter is selected, the Ruby template should be deleted (hidden), and the content from the api (obtained through axios) should be rolled.

Tried it this way:

```
 document.querySelector('.shop-content__grid').innerHTML = `
  <div @click='this.testBtn'>Test</div>
 `;
```

Yes, it removes internal content, but does not read as a view. Is there a legal way to do this? Or are there any other ways to solve the problem?

Comment: You probably have to spend some time reading VueJS 2. If the whole thing is a Vue app, you would never use document selector. If you are using Vue only for a componenet or two in a regular HTML page, then you may have to "render" the Vue component into the respective Div.

Comment: @Teddy What do you mean by ```then you may have to "render" the Vue component into the respective Div.```? And yes, im using vue for 1-2 component in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If its a full blown Vue app, then you are thinking of it in the wrong way. You rarely even use document selector in a Vue app.

If it is just a HTML page with one or two simple Vue components being used, then you may have to provide the element selector and provide the data to define and render the Vue component into that existing HTML element.

For example:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>VueJs Instance</title>
      <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/vue.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id = "vue_det">
         <h1>Firstname : {{firstname}}</h1>
         <h1>Lastname : {{lastname}}</h1>
         <h1>{{mydetails()}}</h1>
      </div>
      <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/vue_instance.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

vue_instance.js

```
var  vm = new Vue({
   el: '#vue_det',
   data: {
      firstname : "Ria",
      lastname  : "Singh",
      address    : "Mumbai"
   },
   methods: {
      mydetails : function() {
         return "I am "+this.firstname +" "+ this.lastname;
      }
   }
})
```

Refer:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#What-is-Vue-js

Also this tutorial:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vuejs/vuejs_instances.htm

In the above example, you are providing the target element, the data and the methods in the component definition itself.

If the data changes, you may have to recreate the component.

Rather than this, if the component listens to an Event bus, you need not render the component again - you could pass (or emit) the data to the component from outside, and it would rerender itself.

Here is a simple event bus example:
https://andrejsabrickis.medium.com/https-medium-com-andrejsabrickis-create-simple-eventbus-to-communicate-between-vue-js-components-cdc11cd59860